# How do I set the opacity of a Button to 0? (Unity)

Tags: unity, c#, unity-ui

I'm trying to hide a button when you click that button (I meant setting the opacity to 0, not disabling the game object of the button). What the button does is it loads a scene async. If I disable the game object I won't be able to load the scene async. Any way to set the opacity of the button?

Sorry if the question is already asked as I wasn't able to find any questions related to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the alpha-value of the renderer of the button to zero. When your button has a text or any other child-nodes, then those also need to be made transparent:

```
foreach(var renderer in GetComponentsInChildren<CanvasRenderer>()) {
    renderer.SetAlpha(0.0f);
}
```

Another way to make a button disappear without also disabling any of the scripts on it is by setting its scale to `0:0:0`. This will also make all its children disappear:

```
GetComponent<RectTransform>().scale = Vector3.zero;
```

However, when your problem is that you need a script which is on the button to run after the button was removed, then I would recommend you to better separate your UI logic from your game logic. The components of an UI element should only govern the UI element itself.

I assume you are building some kind of main menu? In that case I would create one component `MainMenu` and assign it to an invisible gameObject in the scene. I would then give it a method `public void StartGame()` which starts the game (as well as methods for everything else the player can do on the main menu). I would then create a "Start Game" button and then use its OnClick assignment in its inspector to make it call the `MainMenu.StartGame` method of the invisible gameObject. The advantage of this pattern is that you can easily add more ways to call that StartGame method. Like have a keyboard key to call it or call it automatically based on a timer when the player does nothing.

Comment: The second method worked, but I had another strategy. When I click the play button, it loads the Loading Scene, which then loads the Main Scene. This might be a dumb idea, but at least it works.

Comment: @Yeppii A very lightweight scene just for loading the actual game scene asynchronously while visualizing the progress of the load operation is actually a pretty smart idea. Some people call it a "loading screen" :)

Comment: Oh, I do think the same, as the loading scene only contains a UI Text GameObject.